# Getting "err: max fee per gas less than block base fee" when estimating gas cost of a transaction

Tags: ethers.js, javascript, gas-price, gas-estimate, web3-providers

For the last few days, I have some trouble using the `eth_estimateGas` function from the Quick Node provider.

Indeed, after fetching a transaction from the mempool, I want to estimate the gas cost of this transaction, but the following error is always given:

```
Error: processing response error (body="{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":140,\"error\":{\"code\":-32000,\"message\":\"err: max fee per gas less than block base fee: address [ADDRESS], maxFeePerGas: 1000000000 baseFee: 52999024340 (supplied gas 170113)\"}}\n", error={"code":-32000}, requestBody="{\"method\":\"eth_estimateGas\",\"params\":[{\"gas\":\"0x4defb\",\"gasPrice\":\"0x3b9aca00\",\"type\":\"0x0\",\"value\":\"0xaa87bee538000\",\"from\":\"0x0e7c7865e044104961e47b33a254e6c88cc94824\",\"to\":\"0x7a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d\",\"data\":\"0x7ff36ab5000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011c4bd721eeef3e2e97eb00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000800000000000000000000000000e7c7865e044104961e47b33a254e6c88cc9482400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000609776a90000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000c02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc20000000000000000000000004fab740779c73aa3945a5cf6025bf1b0e7f6349c\"}],\"id\":140,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\"}", requestMethod="POST", url="[PROVIDER]", code=SERVER_ERROR, version=web/5.7.1)
```

I have tried a few things like using another provider, or getting the latest fee data of the block and update the transaction maxFeePerGas before estimating the gas cost.

This error is happening on both type 0 and type 2 transactions.

I really don't understand if this error is caused by a problem in my code or is simply due to the ETH network.

Here you can find the part of my code where I am estimating the gas cost:

```js
async function estimateGasCost(transaction) {
    try {
        // Check if the transaction is EIP-1559
        if (transaction.type === 2 && transaction.gasPrice) {
            delete transaction.gasPrice; // Delete gasPrice parameter because it triggers an error on EIP-1559 transactions
        }

        // Estimate the gas cost
        console.log(`Estimating the gas cost...`);
        const transactionGasCost = await provider.estimateGas(transaction);
        return console.log("Transaction gas cost:", transactionGasCost);

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`[isTransactionProfitable]: Error while checking transaction profitability -> ${error}`);
    }
}
```

An example of transaction:

````
{"hash":"0x51e58cfdb46a310ed22d55a57b062f38e7d8d87c0736bf17558e17c4f754ac43","type":0,"accessList":null,"blockHash":null,"blockNumber":null,"transactionIndex":null,"confirmations":0,"from":"0xaF59C288C46440Dead0a796F02054BAdaeb822c3","gasPrice":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x2cb41780"},"gasLimit":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x02f2cb"},"to":"0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D","value":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x08e1bc9bf04000"},"nonce":0,"data":"0x7ff36ab5000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000018f7bce8fb44ae00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080000000000000000000000000af59c288c46440dead0a796f02054badaeb822c300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000618085380000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000c02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc20000000000000000000000008b3192f5eebd8579568a2ed41e6feb402f93f73f","r":"0x656e8478e1a9c0058c84ecbd7335689ec06d2855ca0fa3ee0de2d76bb96b94f1","s":"0x1b0a841af6a773e4ff48ebfc6e4de311d18fc61bf3f86394afa9a37681041c3a","v":38,"creates":null,"chainId":1}```
````